# Unknown column '"' in 'where clause [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp

I am getting this error ***Erreur SQL (1054) : Unknown column 'pk.post_id' in 'where clause'*** when I try to execute this query.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` as pm  
SET pm.post_content = 
   (select meta_value from `wp_postmeta` as pk where pk.post_id = pm.id and pk.meta_key = "_job_description") 
 WHERE  pm.id = pk.post_id;
```

I didn't find out how to fix it. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use double quotes for string or date literals. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string or date literals.

Comment: use single quote.

Comment: `pk.post_id` isn't in scope in the outer query, only in the inner one. You cannot use it in the outer query, remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use multiple-table UPDATE syntax:

```sql
UPDATE `wp_posts` as pm  
JOIN `wp_postmeta` as pk ON pm.id = pk.post_id 
                        AND pk.meta_key = '_job_description'
SET pm.post_content = pk.meta_value;
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html